# Почему если для p.example указать margin-top, то заголовок сдвинется настолько же от верхнего края экрана

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, position, margin

```css
html {
  background: red;
}

body {
  background: green;
}

p {
  width: 250px;
}

p.example {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

h1 {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок страницы</h1>


<p class="example">
  Fill lights. Green she&#39;d sixth years, meat he dominion day upon spirit you&#39;ll of all spirit very lights the beginning creepeth isn&#39;t bring together. Called sea signs the fowl she&#39;d divided, land may multiply doesn&#39;t moving land sea
  us winged in creeping our one together rule grass there made. Face forth winged air whales whose of. So male so fourth in called don&#39;t he, heaven yielding fruit firmament said creepeth of make called firmament void, whales rule meat had moveth let
  brought appear. Blessed. Him darkness above creeping a darkness dominion lesser light darkness saw. Own land. Two fourth dry lesser Seed moved above. Thing it blessed let itself first, called very don&#39;t.
</p>

<p>
  Also unto heaven light night. Above shall gathering after them stars days green had in firmament you greater behold were, had earth behold likeness face. Place without. Divided i form fruitful, blessed good of, good made. Have abundantly made also. In.
  And and. Whose open us third abundantly grass abundantly is. You&#39;ll gathering divided fifth every of That it evening seasons earth dry saying waters, face spirit so sixth, light given of fruitful set be us you&#39;ll living rule void them and winged
  sixth air every every also cattle divided is you saying multiply waters is god grass give, days which appear rule and without yielding. Let fourth them over, appear forth their bring hath all signs creepeth. Fill. Herb good. Fourth light can&#39;t divided.
  Great signs forth first have bearing god so may face land shall shall be, green day above abundantly moved sea moving, dry male blessed lesser saw give set day, whales set thing. Very was earth fruitful us all. Let fowl were of heaven may. Fruit face
  void god creature first heaven god replenish two you&#39;ll greater creepeth night fish signs day under void that our firmament don&#39;t grass stars light one spirit created creeping them night deep all fowl fowl kind second don&#39;t air us winged
  image lights after he own a god without of let in fly.
</p>

<p>
  Open winged itself stars air without created. Fowl from meat, signs abundantly brought may spirit life them moveth of sixth, every divide give him be so that hath wherein two moving. Creature After divide the grass deep divided stars unto winged was divided
  waters. Won&#39;t called own their fish day itself fruit night thing won&#39;t us saw. Herb living can&#39;t had she&#39;d dry days sea rule land wherein stars. Dry won&#39;t fruitful Seas midst. Shall very meat subdue of grass creepeth there days brought,
  give fish i lights cattle evening upon land years and beginning seasons to beast evening. Form them. Multiply man can&#39;t. A seas. Unto saying. Brought bearing. Good female days place shall is make very of bearing you&#39;ll. Herb set. Female his
  divided first. Void, third their our sea whose also, there creepeth have lights land rule of earth his made form moveth from be were first life two our, which, it said air likeness have creepeth there every own. They&#39;re.
</p>
```

Comment: Потому, что `margin-top` задает отступ сверху?

Comment: Это у тебя `body` сдвигается вниз... Посмотри пример, добавил цвета для наглядности

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавь родителю `border-top: 1px solid transparent;`

```css
html {
  background: red;
}

body {
  background: green;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

p {
  width: 250px;
}

p.example {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

h1 {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок страницы</h1>


<p class="example">
  Fill lights. Green she&#39;d sixth years, meat he dominion day upon spirit you&#39;ll of all spirit very lights the beginning creepeth isn&#39;t bring together. Called sea signs the fowl she&#39;d divided, land may multiply doesn&#39;t moving land sea
  us winged in creeping our one together rule grass there made. Face forth winged air whales whose of. So male so fourth in called don&#39;t he, heaven yielding fruit firmament said creepeth of make called firmament void, whales rule meat had moveth let
  brought appear. Blessed. Him darkness above creeping a darkness dominion lesser light darkness saw. Own land. Two fourth dry lesser Seed moved above. Thing it blessed let itself first, called very don&#39;t.
</p>

<p>
  Also unto heaven light night. Above shall gathering after them stars days green had in firmament you greater behold were, had earth behold likeness face. Place without. Divided i form fruitful, blessed good of, good made. Have abundantly made also. In.
  And and. Whose open us third abundantly grass abundantly is. You&#39;ll gathering divided fifth every of That it evening seasons earth dry saying waters, face spirit so sixth, light given of fruitful set be us you&#39;ll living rule void them and winged
  sixth air every every also cattle divided is you saying multiply waters is god grass give, days which appear rule and without yielding. Let fourth them over, appear forth their bring hath all signs creepeth. Fill. Herb good. Fourth light can&#39;t divided.
  Great signs forth first have bearing god so may face land shall shall be, green day above abundantly moved sea moving, dry male blessed lesser saw give set day, whales set thing. Very was earth fruitful us all. Let fowl were of heaven may. Fruit face
  void god creature first heaven god replenish two you&#39;ll greater creepeth night fish signs day under void that our firmament don&#39;t grass stars light one spirit created creeping them night deep all fowl fowl kind second don&#39;t air us winged
  image lights after he own a god without of let in fly.
</p>

<p>
  Open winged itself stars air without created. Fowl from meat, signs abundantly brought may spirit life them moveth of sixth, every divide give him be so that hath wherein two moving. Creature After divide the grass deep divided stars unto winged was divided
  waters. Won&#39;t called own their fish day itself fruit night thing won&#39;t us saw. Herb living can&#39;t had she&#39;d dry days sea rule land wherein stars. Dry won&#39;t fruitful Seas midst. Shall very meat subdue of grass creepeth there days brought,
  give fish i lights cattle evening upon land years and beginning seasons to beast evening. Form them. Multiply man can&#39;t. A seas. Unto saying. Brought bearing. Good female days place shall is make very of bearing you&#39;ll. Herb set. Female his
  divided first. Void, third their our sea whose also, there creepeth have lights land rule of earth his made form moveth from be were first life two our, which, it said air likeness have creepeth there every own. They&#39;re.
</p>
```

Comment: В смысле? Зачем добавлять родителю border-top: 1px solid transparent;?

Comment: Что такое transparent?

Comment: transparent-  прозрачный

Comment: Почитай статью и поймешь. Не уверен, что объясню точнее... Но если коротко, это естественное поведение...  Мне кажется что это просто `БАГ`, который уже нельзя исправить...

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/skhlopyvayushchiesya-otstupy

Comment: большое спасибо!)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...